# bootstrap forbid new line displaying when browser resizes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 grid system to layout my webpage. How to forbid .col-sm-4 to show in a new line? That is, when user browser width changes, I want the horizontal scroll bar show up for overflowing content instead of automatically showing in the next line.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing me to the right direction!